# PHP Symfony4 Doctrine driver/authentication issue (Windows 10)

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, symfony

I've installed PHP, mySQL and Apache as separate components and have a skeleton app built with `Symfony/Composer/Twig`.

I'm trying to create a database using `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` .

The error I'm getting is

> *Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"*
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
>                                                                An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>                               could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>                               could not find driver

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Enabling the `extension=pdo_mysql` in `php.ini`
  This produces a different set of errors related to authentication. I don't understand the ramifications of enabling this extension so unsure if that's a good rabbit hole to be going down or not.
- In `my.ini` (equivalent to my.cnf for many others) I have made `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` based on the suggestions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/924367/php-7-2-8-pdo-fails-to-connect-to-mysql-8-0-12-ga-in-aws-ec2-lemp-stack/924388#924388) I used mySQL Workbench to confirm the directory containing my.ini is where mySQL is pathing (maybe not the correct term).

Many with this issue had problems with unconventional mysql usernames or passwords but I am using `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/appname`

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Did you change your .env variables? And you sure have to enable pdo_mysql. Please see first: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database and after that be sure that you have installed pdo_mysql extension and enabled it.

Comment: I had the problem. I was working on a virtual machine and I was executing the doctrine commands on my "real" laptop. If you're using docker/VM make sure you've set the PDO variables from your webapp host machine and you executed commands in the good terminal.

Comment: Not a docker setup or VM.  I have of course referenced the official documentation but my .env looks right. I think my environment variables are ok because I can create and administer mysql databases from mysql Workbench. When you say 'installed pdo_mysql extension and enabled it' that refers to uncommenting ;extension=pdo_mysql in php.ini, right? Is there an additional install step I am missing somewhere? So frustrating but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you marked the question tagged: windows. Based on that, we can have the project running in a virtual environment (VitualBox), if in the virtual environment it was Enabling the `extension=pdo_mysql` in **php.ini**, but the command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` or `php.exe bin/console doctrine:database:create` run on the local machine and not the virtual one; you will need to enable `extension=pdo_mysql` in **php.ini** in the local development environment (**C:\php\php.ini**)